# How can I get xrandr to realize my screens are of a different height?

Tags: x11, i3, xrandr, multi-monitor, conky

On Manjaro Linux using i3, I have an issue with lining up my two monitors to achieve seamless transition. Currently they look fine using this command to orient them:

```
xrandr --output USB-C-0 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --rate 75 --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080 --rotate left --rate 59.98 --left-of  USB-C-0
```

However when moving my mouse from right to left, it awkwardly jumps about halfway up the screen (e.g. if I moved it from the bottom left of my normal screen it would end up about in the middle of the left screen).

I suspect this is due to a quirk with how xrandr is orienting my virtual desktop. When I take a picture with arandr open you can see that there's a large empty space below my main monitor.

[image]

Attempting to put the monitor in the correct position with arandr results in the second image, having everything on my right screen being shifted up.

[image]

I've tried to use the `--pos` flag with xrandr but it seems to have no effect, possibly due to weirdness with having differently oriented screens. It's unclear to me how to get xrandr to recognize that my right screen is not the same height as my left.